# Ошибка в коде php при создание окна регистрации

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. Стал писать форму для регистрации/авторизации на сайте и по началу начальные поля выходили, но после стала выходить ошибка как на скриншоте.
P.S. Искал в интернете, ничего не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста новичку.

! https://ibb.co/eOhYEp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все, нашел свою ошибку. В папке libs файл был не rb.php , а rb-mysql.php . 
Может кому-то мой опыт будет полезен)